# Invalid Key File Error -- Parity Node Ethereum Wallet

Tags: parity

Had the parity node running with ethereum wallet smoothly until block 2,300,000 or so. Then I received this error:

```
2017-08-13 21:11:31  Invalid key file: "/Users/kylekenyon/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/keys/ethereum/dapps_history.json" (Syntax(Custom("Unknown field: \'\'"), 1, 3))
```

The wallet is no longer syncing and I'm not sure what to do. I'm not extremely "computer literate" so a simplified answer would be awesome.

Comment: Can you share more lines of the log output? The invalid key file is just a warning and can be ignored (probably).

Comment: @Afri I also have this error. But only on `chain=ropsten`, `chain=kovan` works fine. What can I do against this error? I think it issues errors, so I can't deploy contracts on `ropsten`